# How to find the version of a File on windows through Java program?

Tags: java

I want to design a function in Java which will have prototype like this.

```
public String FindVersion(String FullPath)
{

}
```

where FullPath can be: `C:\tmp\readme.txt`
or `C:\windows\system32\xcopy.exe`
or like `C:\windows\system3`

Comment: Welcome to SO. To format code, use the `{}` button in the editor. For inline code use back-quotes.  Also, your question is very unclear, for example what do you mean by "version of a file"?

Comment: I didn't know that text files and directories had 'versions'.  Some executables do not even have versions (that they will report).

Comment: We need to know what version means to you.

Comment: Step 1: Know what you want to do. Step 2: Know how to do it. It always surprises me how often programmers assume they can skip step 1.

Comment: Version means file version. So when you right click on some dll or exe, you can see File version under the details tab. I am looking to find that information through Java program.
Try this with: C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe

Answer (score 1):

FileVersionInfo is a Win32 API thing so you'll need to use the JNI and some C code to get access to it or use an external library. There is a an API I found called [Sigar](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar) that seems to be able to do this

Answer (score 1):

The details that you are asking are very specific to the file-system of the operating system on which the Java runs. As of until Java 7(java.nio.file.attribute); we don't have any API that gives you this information. The only option is to make use of some Win 32 API through the JNI interface.

Comment: The Windows API is GetFileVersionInfo at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not all files track versioning, the average text file has no concept stored within the file or externally which encodes how many times it has been edited.

Some documents optionally store versioning information within the document, if enabled.  For those files, the routine would look something like (in pseudocode)

```
public String FindVersion(String filepath) {
   check to see if file type can be deduced;
   check to see if the deduced file type supports versioning;
   check to see if the file has versioning information;
   go through the revisions of the file and report the latest one;
}
```

Some documents are versioned, but the versioning information is not stored within the document, it is stored in a system which tracks the versioning information independently of the document.  In such a case, you really want to deal with the revision control system which is authoratative over the document.  Often such system have utilities to indicate which version of the controlled document was last retreived; other times you need to query the document against all revisions looking for the closest match.

Basically, there's not one way to do it for every situation.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
What if I would say that I am only interested in .dll, .exe and .sys files ?
Currently I create one VBscript and then call it from Java program and then collect the version from the VBScript output. 
Is there any other way ?